# whether image file extention is excaidraw.svg or draw.svg

Tags: java

I'm using a jekyll theme called 'multiverse' at my `https://github/appstew/appstew-github-io`. My blog is `appstew.github.io`.

In my _layout/multiverse.html, I wanted to implement code that checks whether a filename ends with `excalidraw.svg` or `drawio.svg`.

I'm on Java bootcamp and barely know about html/js/css. I searched and tried to make a proper code for 1 hour already with no avail.
I have no more time to do this currently.

It would be very easy in Java, but I couldn't do it in this html code.

```html
    {% for image in site.images %}
    <article class="thumb">
      <a href="{{site.baseurl}}/images/{{ image.path | split: '/' | last | split: '.' | first }}.html">
        
        <img src="{{site.baseurl}}/img/{{ image.path | split: '/' | last | split: '.' | first }}.excalidraw.svg" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
        
        <img src="{{site.baseurl}}/img/{{ image.path | split: '/' | last | split: '.' | first }}.drawio.svg" alt="{{ image.title }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would just be to fetch the name of the file as a string and check `*filename*.endsWith("drawio.svg")` on it.